# Postgresql - Optimize ordering of columns in table range partitioning with multiple columns range

Tags: postgresql, composite-primary-key, table-partitioning, range-partitions

I am testing with creating a data warehouse for a relatively big dataset. Based on ~10% sample of the data I decided to partition some tables that are expected to exceed memory which currently 16GB
Based on the recommendation in [postgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-OVERVIEW): (edited)

> These benefits will normally be worthwhile only when a table would otherwise be very large. The exact point at which a table will benefit from partitioning depends on the application, although a rule of thumb is that the size of the table should exceed the physical memory of the database server.

One particular table I am not sure how to partition, this table is frequently queried in 2 different ways, with `WHERE` clause that may include primary key `OR` another indexed column, so figured I need a range partition using the existing primary key and the other column (with the other column added to the primary key).

**Knowing that the order of columns matters, and given the below information my question is:**
What is the best order for primary key and range partitioning columns?

Original table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE items (
    item_id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL, -- primary key
    src_doc_id bigint NOT NULL, -- every item can exist in one src_doc only and a src_doc can have multiple items 
    item_name character varying(50) NOT NULL, -- used in `WHERE` clause with src_doc_id and guaranteed to be unique from source
    attr_1 bool,
    attr_2 bool, -- +15 other columns all bool or integer types
    PRIMARY KEY (item_id)
);
CREATE INDEX index_items_src_doc_id ON items USING btree (src_doc_id);
CREATE INDEX index_items_item_name ON items USING hash (item_name);
```

Table size for 10% of the dataset is ~2GB (result of pg_total_relation_size) with 3M+ rows, loading or querying performance is excellent, but thinking that this table is expected to grow to 30M rows and size 20GB I do not know what to expect in terms of performance.

Partitioned table being considered:

```sql
CREATE TABLE items (
    item_id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL,
    src_doc_id bigint NOT NULL,
    item_name character varying(50) NOT NULL,
    attr_1 bool,
    attr_2 bool,
    PRIMARY KEY (item_id, src_doc_id) -- should the order be reversed?
) PARTITION BY RANGE (item_id, src_doc_id); -- should the order be reversed?
CREATE INDEX index_items_src_doc_id ON items USING btree (src_doc_id);
CREATE INDEX index_items_item_name ON items USING hash (item_name);

-- Ranges are not initially known, so maxvalue is used as upper bound,
-- when upper bound is known, partition is detached and reattached using
-- known known upper bound and a new partition is added for the next range
CREATE TABLE items_00 PARTITION OF items FOR VALUES FROM (MINVALUE, MINVALUE) TO (MAXVALUE, MAXVALUE);
```

**Table usage**

On loading data, the load process (python script) looks up existing items based on `src_doc_id` and `item_name` and stores item_id, so it does not reinsert existing items. `Item_id` gets referenced in lot of other tables, no foreign keys are used.

On querying for analytics item information is always looked up based on `item_id`.

So I can't decide the suitable order for the table `PRIMARY KEY` and `PARTITION BY RANGE`,
Should it be `(item_id, src_doc_id)` or `(src_doc_id, item_id)`?

Comment: 16GB is pretty small. You should measure if you really get performance benefit out of partitioning.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe just to clarify, are you referring to memory or table size? anyway 16GB is the memory I have available currently, it can be extended if this database proves useful, also the sizes I mentioned are for intital load only, database is exepected to grow beyond that if recent data is added regulary after initial load.

Comment: I mean, 16GB is not a large table, and I am not sure if that is worth partitioning. You'd have to experiment.

Comment: The doc doesn't say a table shouldn't be larger than memory.  My reading of it is that you shouldn't even *start* to think about partitioning until it does exceed the size of memory.  Which seems like a good rule of thumb, but I would probably add "And even then, you should usually conclude 'no'".

Comment: @jjanes thank you, that's good to know! In my case I think I will eventually need partitioning, just trying to think ahead. Just edited to reflect what the documents actually say, thank you for pointing that out.